# django-crispy-forms how to insert size option in one Input field?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

In my crispy form, I would like to insert a size="3" in only one of the input fields so it would match its maxlength.  I tried inserting size the same way maxlength is inserted when defining bpm as a CharField but it didn't work.

Currently when rendered, it shows

```
<input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_bpm" maxlength="3" name="bpm" type="text" />
```

But I would like to change it to show

```
<input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_bpm" maxlength="3" size="3" name="bpm" type="text" />
```

In my forms template I call {% crispy form %}

In my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile, Artist
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Div
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import StrictButton, FormActions

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "artist",
            "title",
            "mix",
            "bpm",
            "genre",
            ]

    artist = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)        
    bpm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, max_length=3)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'artist',
            'title',
            'mix',
            'bpm',
            'genre',
            FormActions(Div(Submit('submit','Submit', css_class='btn-primary'), style="float: right")),
        )

    def clean_artist(self):
        artist = self.cleaned_data.get("artist")
        if not artist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Artist is a required field.")
        else:
            artist, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=artist)
            return artist
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Field` layout object to specify any [attributes](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#layout-objects-attributes) for your layout object:

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Field

self.helper.layout = Layout(
    'artist',
    'title',
    'mix',
    Field('bpm', size=3),
    'genre',
    # ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

May not the 100% match answer, but useful to me:
Use Row + Col control the width

```py
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Row(Column("type", css_class="col-3"), Column("minutes_down", 
    css_class="col-3"), css_class="ml-0"),
    Row(Column("comments", css_class="col-6"), css_class="ml-0"),
....
```

or try:

```
Field("comments", css_class="form-control form-control-lg w-100")
```